# How to find inverted function values

Tags: functions

I have this function:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}(x-3) $$$$f:(0,6]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
The question goes:

> Make sure that for every $a\in(0,6]$  holds $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$

First i proved that the function is an injective function.

I found the inverted function: $f^{-1}(x)= 3x+3$

But from here I'm stuck.

 i'm not sure what I need to do next.


Thanks.

Comment: I think you are done.

Comment: Take $x=f(a)$ in your formula for $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: It's called "inverse", not inverted.

Comment: @jjagmath You are right, sorry, English is not my main language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the inverse function defined by $f^{-1}(a)=3a+3$ which is well defined $\forall a \in (0,6]$, now just replace $x$ with $f^{-1}(a)$ as input of the function $f$:
$$\forall a \in (0,6], f(f^{-1}(a)) = {1\over 3} (f^{-1}(a) - 3) = {1\over 3} ((3a+3) - 3) = a$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! now I understand.